# Expectation of two successive martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Consider a martingale $(M_n)_{n \geq 0}$ adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n \geq 0}$. I want to prove that: 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[M_nM_{n+1}] = \mathbb{E}[M_n^2].
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align} 
\mathbb{E}[M_nM_{n+1}] &= \mathbb{E}[M_nM_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_0] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[ \mathbb{E}[M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \cdot M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_0 \big] \\
&\text{$= \mathbb{E}[ M_{n+1} \cdot M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_0 ]\qquad$ since $\mathcal{F}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_n^*$} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[ M_{n+1} \cdot M_{n+1}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[ M_{n+1}^2].
\end{align}

*If $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[ \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{A} ] \mid \mathcal{B} \big] = \mathbb{E}\big[ \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{B} ] \mid \mathcal{A} \big] =  \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{A} ].
\end{align}
What happened? Why is this solution not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity

> $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \cdot M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_0) = \mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_0)$

does not hold true. You cannot apply $(\ast)$ to justify this identity because the term at the left-hand side is not of the form

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{A}) \mid \mathcal{B})$$

but of the (more general) form

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{A}) \cdot Y \mid \mathcal{B}).$$

---

**Hint:** Write

$$\mathbb{E}(M_n \cdot M_{n+1}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} \cdot M_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n))$$

and use the pull out property.

Comment: Okido! Naturally, such a term can not be neglected. From your hint it is obvious that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}\cdot M_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n]] =  \mathbb{E}[ M_n \mathbb{E}[M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n]] = \mathbb{E}[M_n^2]$. But why can you write $\mathbb{E}[M_n \cdot M_{n+1}] = \mathcal{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}\cdot M_n \mid \mathcal{F}_n]]$?

Comment: @iJup This follows from $(\ast)$ with $\mathcal{A} := \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ (i.e. the trivial $\sigma$-algebra) and $\mathcal{B} := \mathcal{F}_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is your third equality. The property (*) that you are trying to use may no longer be valid as you are multiplying $\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1} | F_n]$ by $M_{n+1}$. Have you checked the proof to see if it could be modified to account for the addition of such a term?